# HTML Canvas z-index on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

> HTML5 canvas, on click `button` z-index canvas overlay.

Default, Red big circle over overlay and and skyblue circles behind the overlay. On click 'button' skyblue circle should come over overlay and big circle should go behind.

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/o9b2sqkq/)

[image]

Comment: you need to redraw the image in a different order(orange, overlay, blue) or use multiple canvases.

Comment: How does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/2PzBq/1/

Comment: look at the `draw` function. It first makes the canvas white then draws the rectangles. This function is called each second so the image is redrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your draw-all-orbits and draw-all-bodies code in reusable functions

```
function drawAllOrbits(){
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';
    for(var i=0;i<orbits.length;i++){
      drawOrbit(orbits[i]);
    }
}

function drawAllBodies(){
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
      drawOrbitingCircle(circles[i]);
    }
}
```

Give your button an id

```
<button id='theButton'>Click</button>
```

Listen for click events on the button.

```
$('#theButton').on('click',function(){ ... });
```

When  clicked, clear the canvas and redraw the scene in your desired order.

```
$('#theButton').on('click',function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    circle();
    ovarlay();
    drawAllOrbits();
    drawAllBodies();
});
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
// vars for canvas
var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx= canvas.getContext('2d'),
cw=canvas.width,
ch=canvas.height,
cx=cw/2,
cy=ch/2;

// vars for orbits & circle-bodies
var circleRadius=12;
var orbits=[80,130];
var circleCountByOrbit=[5,8];
var circles=[];

// flag to indicate which scene to display
var highlightTomato=true;

// calc semi-random orbiting bodies
for(var o=0;o<orbits.length;o++){
 var count=circleCountByOrbit[o];
 var sweep=Math.PI*2/count;
 for(var c=0;c<count;c++){
  var midAngle=(sweep*c)+sweep/2;
  var randomOffset=Math.random()*0.50-1;
  var angle=midAngle+sweep*randomOffset;
  circles.push({orbitIndex:o, angle:angle});
 }
}

// draw the initial scene
drawHighlightedTomato();

// listen for button click and toggle the scene
$('#theButton').on('click',function(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  highlightTomato=!highlightTomato;
  if(highlightTomato){
      drawHighlightedTomato();
  }else{
      drawHighlightedBodies();
  }
});


///////////////////////////////
// functions to draw scenes
///////////////////////////////

function drawHighlightedTomato(){
    drawAllOrbits();
    drawAllBodies();
    ovarlay();
    circle();
}

function drawHighlightedBodies(){
    circle();
    ovarlay();
    drawAllOrbits();
    drawAllBodies();
}

function drawOrbit(radius){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
 ctx.stroke();    
}

function drawOrbitingCircle(circle){
 var x=cx+orbits[circle.orbitIndex]*Math.cos(circle.angle);
 var y=cy+orbits[circle.orbitIndex]*Math.sin(circle.angle);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(x,y,circleRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
 ctx.fillStyle='#1bb0e7';
 ctx.fill();
 ctx.strokeStyle='white';
 ctx.stroke();
}

function drawAllOrbits(){
    ctx.strokeStyle='black';
    for(var i=0;i<orbits.length;i++){
      drawOrbit(orbits[i]);
    }
}

function drawAllBodies(){
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
      drawOrbitingCircle(circles[i]);
    }
}

function circle(place){
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,40,0,100);
  ctx.fillStyle='tomato';
  ctx.fill();
}

function ovarlay(backgroundOverlay){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.rect(0, 0, cw, ch);
 ctx.fillStyle='rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';
 ctx.fill();
 //ctx.zindex= 1;
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id=theButton>Toggle</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```